# Python split('\n') breaks a row midway instead of after end of line

Tags: python, split, subprocess, strip

I'm trying to parse the output of a SQL query in Python (cannot install cx_Oracle due to org restrictions, hence have to go the subprocess way.

Here is my output of a subprocess command

```
output1 = sqlplus.communicate()[0].split('\n')

['', '05/02/2016 19:42:40,ABC,O\t\t\t\t  ,ACTIVE', '\t   49', '', '05/02/2016 19:42:40,ABC,O\t\t\t  ,INACTIVE', '\t   11', '']
```

So that the date makes sense, i'm trying to remove all white spaces and tabs but there is one column that is giving me a headache.

When i try to remove extra stuff from earlier output with below code, the last column gets bumped to the next row instead of remaining in the same row. I know it is probably because of the leading \t (tab) in the last column, but i'm unable to remove it. I've been trying since hours using strip, lstrip, rstrip, regexes but to no avail.

```
for line in output1:
    if(line != ''):
            print ",".join([str(x.strip()) for x in line.split(',')])
```

Below is my final output, but with the last column in next row

```
05/02/2016 19:53:52,ABC,O,ACTIVE
49
05/02/2016 19:53:52,ABC,O,INACTIVE
11
```

Need some help finding out what i'm missing. Thanks in advance for all your inputs :)

--Jim

Comment: Your `output1` seems to show that the "last column" is, in fact, *already* on a new line in the `communicate()` output. Look at how the second string ends right after `ACTIVE`, and then `'\t   49'` is the third string. Are you sure the output of the external command looks the way you think it does?

Comment: Maybe the external command is inserting line breaks to try to do its own line wrapping.

Comment: Your code ignores the empty strings and removes any whitespace around the commas in comma-separated values. But it doesn't combine separate elements of the list into a single line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want each row to be the strings in between the empty strings in your list? These empty strings are created by split() on '/n/n', so where there is a blank line. You could just split on those blank lines first:

```
output1 = '\n05/02/2016 19:42:40,ABC,O\t\t\t\t  ,ACTIVE\n\t   49\n\n05/02/2016 19:42:40,ABC,O\t\t\t  ,INACTIVE\n\t   11\n'
output1 = output1.split('\n\n')
```

You can then use a series of replacements, splits, strips, and joins to reassemble, splitting on commas and white space except spaces.

```
for line in output1:
    line = line.replace(' ', '(^_^)')
    line = line.split()
    line = [word.replace('(^_^)', ' ').strip() for word in line]
    line = ','.join([word.strip(',') for word in line])
    print line
```

Comment: Your method worked but only once case is left out ...
 ,INACTIVE', '\t<four_spaces_here>4',
What do i do about this one?

Comment: I don't see that case in the output you provided. Could you describe the format of the output from sqlplus, or maybe include your subprocess.Popen or subprocess.call call?

Comment: Finally i did it this way (applied a regex to select only the characters i want, and then split on comma.
    line = re.sub("[^0-9, a-zA-Z:\/]",'',line)line = line.split(',')
This definitely leaves some spaces around my actual data, but since i'm inserting stuff back to Oracle i removed the multiple whitespaces using Oracle TRIM(). Thx for your help!